# Inheritance in Rails lib directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, inheritance, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to make some classes inherit from a base class in the Rails lib directory.

The setup is as follows:

```
#lib/ab_tests/base.rb
module AbTests
  class Base
    # some methods...
  end
end

#lib/ab_tests/first_test.rb
module AbTests
  class FirstTest < AbTests::Base
    # some methods...
  end
end
```

I require these files in `config/application.rb` in a fairly standard way

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/lib/ab_tests)
```

However, whenever I try to start the server, I get a fatal `LoadError`:

```
[some path].../activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:503:in `load_missing_constant': Expected [project name]/lib/ab_tests/base.rb to define Base (LoadError)
```

I've tried both of the following and it's the same issue every time.

```
#lib/ab_tests/first_test.rb
class FirstTest < ::AbTests::Base

#lib/ab_tests/first_test.rb
class FirstTest < Base
```

Also, if I remove the reference to `AbTests::Base` from `lib/ab_tests/base.rb` then there is no load error so it's not simply the fact that the class exists that causes the problem. The problem only occurs when I try to use it.

How can I accomplish this inheritance and why is this problem occurring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually structure these things like this:

```
-lib
  |- ab_tests.rb
  |- ab_tests/
       |- base.rb
       |- first_test.rb
```

Where `ab_tests.rb` is:

```
module AbTests
end
```

The `base.rb` and `first_test.rb` files should be as you've listed them in the first example, except you don't need to specify the namespace when you're declaring it within the module (i.e., just use `class FirstTest < Base` instead of `class FirstTest < AbTests::Base`).